# What does this one-line, macro function, 'static_assert' do?

Tags: c

This is the code I found

```
static_assert(sizeof(struct File) == 256);
```

The definition of the macro is this:

```
#define static_assert(x)    switch (x) case 0: case (x):
```

1. How does this perform assertion?
2. Why not just use the regular assert() function?

Comment: Only the second part of the question is related to the duplicate. The first part (how does it work) is not part of the supposed duplicate question, and it is also not explained in any of the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This performs an `assert` by triggering a compile-time error. Consider this code:

```
switch(0) case 0: case 0:
```

The compiler will tell you that you have a duplicate `case` label, because zero is listed twice. If, on the other hand, you would put any number other than zero in place of `x`, you would get

```
switch(1) case 0: case 1:
```

which is perfectly legal, and would not trigger a compile-time error.

Unlike the regular `assert` which happens at run time, this assert happens at compile time. In other words, if the regular assertion is false, the program would crash; if this assertion is false, the program would not even compile.